# In app Purchase removal for new update ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have current version of the app in App store with IAP. For new update of current app i want to remove IAP. I have removed IAP related code from the app.

My questions are:

1. Shall I remove IAP products from iTunes also for new update?
2. Will that effect current version of the app?
3. If I don't remove IAP products from iTunes, will reviewer reject app on basis of app dont have IAP related code but its still there in iTunes.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: We once created IAP items for a future version but didn't submit them with the next version and we got rejected. We then wrote the reviewer that we needed them for a release in the future and the app was approved. So if you don't remove them from iTunes (maybe you need them again in a later version), then better leave a note to the reviewer. Also make sure you disable the In-App Purchase in the "Capabilities" section of your project settings.

Comment: you must not remove anything from the iTunes portal once you have added it for any previous version (because the clients won't update automatically for the new version, or they may never updated to the new version and you have to keep the old one fully functioning as it was!), but your new version is not forced to implement purchase features for all available _products_.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove code it doesn't matter but must to keep In-APP PRODUCTS as it is. for previous version.